# How to install Windows UWP application package on Real device or Emulator?

Tags: windows, uwp

I am working on Windows 10 UWP application.

I want to know the steps to install Windows 10 UWP application on Windows phone and Emulator as in Android we can install apk file on Emulator and on Windows phone.

Comment: this is very basic ... I think you need to do more research

Answer (score 0):

After anniversary update of windows 10 you can install any UWP app package (.appxbundle) directly, without need of any windows powershell command. Go to settings -> update & security -> for developers and enable Sideload apps. Then just tap or double click on app package and it'll get  installed. If you want to test it on emulator just upload the file on any cloud storage and download it from emulator and run it.